# Weird "padding" between bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out why there's a white space in between my columns in this really simple row. I would like the elemenets to be touching each other and to fill up the 100% of the column space which they don't even with a 100% width? Added a universal selector with a border so the empty space is visible.

```css
* {
  border: 5px solid;
}
.long-brick1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.long-brick2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.long-brick3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="long-brick1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="long-brick2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="long-brick3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="long-brick2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="long-brick3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="long-brick2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--row -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your sample shows perfectly normal Bootstrap behaviour. Any `col-*` div will have a left and right padding of 15 px.

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro for additional information about Bootstrap grid system.

Of course you may override this default behaviour by resetting this default padding for `col-md-2` or any other desired class:

```
.col-md-2 {padding: 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) `col-*` have *padding-left* and *padding-right* of *15px* each.

To get rid of the default padding, you need to apply your custom style to that effect.

You need to do something like this:

```
.col-md-2 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
* {border:5px solid;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;  
 }
```

try this as a instant solution.
    its better to use custom class like

```
   .nopad{ 
     padding:0 !important;
    }
   .nomargin{
     margin: 0px !important;
    }
```

and call this class when you need them like-

```
<div class="col-md-2 nopad">
 <div class="long-brick2">   
 </div>
</div>
```

maybe you are confused about '!important' [ A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document] 
Happy coding :)

Comment: Yep, that worked, will accept when it let me. Why did it happen though? I either never noticed the gap between columns but I think it's not by default?

Comment: I don't recommend setting all elements in the DOM with 0 padding-left and right.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use the `*` selector just to remove some padding.

Comment: @Sergi its bootstrap default div[col-*] padding

Comment: @NickyTheWrench I now its a bad idea. Just a instant answer. and what about when he use col-md-2 again for another page. 
its better to make some usefull class before custom CSS like-

.nopad{padding:0 !important;}

when we need we just call that class.